# TSQL : Can't concatenate strings in while loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to concatenate strings with code

```
DECLARE @separator [nchar](1) = '|',
         @urlList [nvarchar](4000) = '',
         @urlTemp [nvarchar](4000);

DECLARE UrlCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [FileName] FROM [stgInfo];

OPEN UrlCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM UrlCursor INTO @urlTemp;
SET @urlList += @urlTemp;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
         SET @urlList += @separator + @urlTemp;
         FETCH NEXT FROM UrlCursor INTO @urlTemp;
   END
CLOSE UrlCursor;
DEALLOCATE UrlCursor;
```

So, in `@urlList` I get only one value.

But printing

```
   BEGIN
         print @urlTemp;
         FETCH NEXT FROM UrlCursor INTO @urlTemp;
   END
```

returns all values as well.

Can somebody explain how to fix script for getting all values?

Here's table declaration:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE [stgInfo]
(
    [Guid]      [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Number]    [nvarchar](100)    NULL,
    [OrderDate] [nvarchar](20)     NULL,
    [JrnType]   [nchar](10)        NULL,
    [Status]    [nchar](20)        NULL,
    [FileName]  [nchar](300)       NULL,

    CONSTRAINT   [PK_stgInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
         [Guid] ASC
    )
    WITH
    (
         PAD_INDEX = OFF,
         STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    )
    ON [PRIMARY]
)
ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

Followed on stackoverflow's rules I'm adding this text to my question, because it says that is question contains mostly code.

Comment: Can you include what version of SQL Server you are using and what the final result should look like?

Comment: @AlanBurstein MSQL Server 2012, have colunm with urls, wanna get string like 'url1|url2|url3' for list imitation.

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff why ur going in that way where you have some functions available to do that task ??

Comment: @YogeshSharma I'm gonna pass this string into CLR function, because I gues that there's no way to use list-like data in magic tsql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's four different approaches using the following sample data:

```
-- using table variable for sample data
declare @stginfo table ([filename] varchar(4000));
insert @stginfo values ('abc.txt'),('zzz.sql'),('hellokitty.bat');
```

**Option 1: variable concatination**

```
DECLARE @separator [nchar](1) = N'|',
         @urlList [nvarchar](4000) = N'',
         @urlTemp [nvarchar](4000);

SELECT @urlList += [FileName]+@separator
FROM @stgInfo; -- Order by is not guaranteed with this method

SELECT urlList = substring(@urlList,1,len(@urlList)-1);
```

**Option 2: for xml path('') No XML Protection**

```
SELECT urlList = 
STUFF((
  SELECT [filename] + @separator
  FROM @stginfo
  ORDER BY [filename] -- only required if you must get this text in a specific order
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

**Option 3: for xml path('') With XML Protection**

```
SELECT urlList = 
STUFF((
  SELECT [filename] + @separator
  FROM @stginfo
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'),1,1,'')
```

**Option 4: STRING_AGG (SQL Server 2017 only)**

```
SELECT urlList = STRING_AGG([filename],'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Filename])
FROM @stginfo;
```

Comment: Note that I saw that you're using SQL Server 2012 after I posted. I'll leave my answer up nonetheless in case anyone else was curious about `STRING_AGG` or `WITHIN GROUPS`

Comment: You might want to separate your answers to different code blocks, and convert the remarks to headlines. it will make it much more readable.

Comment: Agreed - I changed it. I sometimes post the way I did so people can just copy/paste the code into ssms and run it but your suggestion is better.

Comment: They still can, only now they need to pay a little more attention when they do, and your answer is much clearer this way. +1.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to mimic group concat is to use `for xml` and `stuff`:

```
SELECT @urlList = STUFF(
    (SELECT '|' + [FileName] 
     FROM [stgInfo]
     FOR XML PATH(''))
, 1, 1, '')
```

The inner select concatenates the separator with the column value, and the stuff removes the first separator.

Comment: still return just one value

Comment: Careful - If the possibility exists that their are going to be special XML characters such as &<> as well as any ascii(1) through ascii(32) characters then you want to include the values clause which I demonstrate in my answer above.

Comment: @AntoshaShmonoff it should return just one value - a value that contains a pipe-delimited list of file names. BTW, while file names can't contain unsafe XML characters, Alan is still correct. His option 3 is XML safe.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in data type `[FileName][nchar](300) NULL,` - just need to change to nvarchar. Thanks everyone for brilliant solutions, I'll certainly use them.

Comment: It's very goos you found the problem and posted it. It's the kind of problem that could take hours to find, you might have helped some future readers with this answer.